# Translate a Django app in Arabic and also make forms LTR to RTL

Tags: django, internationalization, translation

I have translated a Django app in multiple languages and everything works fine. But when I switch it to Arabic language I want to make all forms LTR to RTL. How can I achieve this in Django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with RTL, but this [guide](https://lokalise.com/blog/advanced-django-internationalization/) covers it.
It seems that you just have to add this to your root HTML file:

```
{% load i18n %}
{% get_current_language_bidi as LANGUAGE_BIDI %}  <!-- 1 -->
<html dir="{% if LANGUAGE_BIDI %}rtl{% else %}ltr{% endif %}">  <!-- 2 -->
I am displayed in the right direction.
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @ChrisRob. It worked for me. Just we have to use bootstrap5 for better result.